Log4j2 YAML Configuration Not Loaded in Deployed Environment When Using Custom Logging Library in Spring Boot
I'm developing a Spring Boot application (Project A) that uses a custom logging library (Dependency B) to encapsulate all logging configurations, including Log4j2 with a log4j2.yaml file.
Problem:
Locally: When I run the application on my local machine (e.g., via IDE or mvn spring-boot:run), the log4j2.yaml configuration is correctly picked up, and logging works as expected.
Deployed Environment: When I deploy the application to a staging or production environment (e.g., Docker container, cloud platform), the log4j2.yaml configuration is not being picked up. The application falls back to default logging configurations.
Details:
Project Structure:
Project A (Main Application):
Depends on Dependency B.
Does not include any direct Log4j2 configuration files.
Dependency B (Custom Logging Library):
Contains log4j2.yaml in its src/main/resources directory.
Includes code to programmatically load the Log4j2 configuration (because default structured not worked).
Why is log4j2.yaml not being picked up in the deployed environment when it works locally?
Is there a recommended way to package resources in a custom library so that they are accessible in dependent projects during deployment?
What I've Tried:
Ensured Resource Inclusion:
Verified that log4j2.yaml is included in the JAR/WAR file of the custom logging library.
Confirmed that the resource is present when inspecting the packaged artifact.
Classpath Verification:
Made sure that the log4j2.yaml file is accessible via the classpath in the deployed environment.
Used System.out.println statements to print out the path and whether the resource exists.
System Properties:
Tried setting the log4j2.configurationFile system property to point to the log4j2.yaml file.
Example: -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2.yaml
File Permissions and Paths:
Checked file permissions in the deployed environment to ensure the application can read the configuration file.
Ensured there are no path issues or differences between local and deployed environments.
Resource Loading Mechanism:
Tested alternative resource loading methods.
Used absolute paths, but this isn't ideal  and did not work since it should work with classpath resources.

Have you tried -Dlogging.config=log4j2.yaml?

"Includes code to programmatically load the Log4j2 configuration (because default structured not worked)."—what kind of code you are using? Please run your application with -Dlog4j2.debug or -Dlog4j2.statusLoggerLevel=DEBUG to troubleshoot the configuration loading.
